# Invisible FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, layout, invisible

I have a problem with Invisible Frame layout

```
public void Viditelnost(Integer ktore){
    ImageButton Down = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stDown);
    ImageButton Up = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stuUP);
    TextView SetTo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setto);
    LinearLayout stlp = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bocnystlp);

    if (ktore==0) {
        Down.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        SetTo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stlp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
        Down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

<LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                            android:baselineAligned="false"
                            android:id="@+id/bocnystlp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.1"
                            android:padding="2dp">
```

If I start Method Viditelnost My program crashed, but I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: what line is crashing? kde ti to crashuje?

Comment: To je moja angličtina až taká zlá? :) .. viem
this line TextView SetTo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setto);
When I remove this line, App run good. Thaks

Comment: theMatus čo mám robiť aby som mohol aj po nejakých 3 otázkach dať otázky? lebo vždy ma to po pár dnoch blokne a to aj radím odporučam aj konečné odpovede som mal aj všetko, vieš mi to vysvetliť prosím?

Comment: Do you have an element with id "setto" in your xml?

Comment: paradox paradox, to ti presne neviem vysvetlit, ako hlavne co je, tak vzdy to poriadne poprehladavaj, ci nahodou nenajdes odpoved tu alebo inde, ja osobne som zatial mal 3 otazky, na vsetky som si odpovedal sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your logcat? Where exactly does the program crash?

stlp is a LinearLayout, to hide it try

stlp.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);